# What are the structural rules for arc reversal in a Bayesian network?

Tags: bayesian-network

Given a Bayesian network, if I reverse the edge from $X \rightarrow Y$,
what additional edges do I need to add to the structure of the network?

I know that there are some rules about linking (adding edges amongst) the parents (and/or children)
for one or both of $X,Y$, but I haven't found a good concise set of rules on line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My read of [this paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~cebly/Papers/simulation.pdf) indicates that:

1. All of the parents of $X$ are added to the set of parents of $Y$,
2. All of the parents of $Y$ are added to the set of  parents of $X$,
3. No relationships among the descendants (or the grandparents) of  $X,Y$ are affected.

Depending on the specific probability distributions involved, some the newly
added relations may be dropped, i.e. due to the nature of the distributions 
there is some particular parent of $X$ that $Y$ ends up dropping out of the
the conditional relationship.

Answer (score 2):

It looks Arc Reversal is defined in Theorem 3 in this paper: http://cs.ru.nl/~peterl/BN/shachter1987.pdf

"Given that there is an arc (i,j) between chance nodes i and j, but no other directed (i-j)-path in a regular influence diagram, arg(i,j) can be replaced by arc(j,i). Afterward, both nodes inherit each other's conditional predecessors.